# Increase value of element based on checkbox status

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I can't seem to figure out a way of increasing value of SPAN based on checkboxes checked.
For example I have 3 checkboxes

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" id ="one"/>One
    <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" id="two"/>Two
    <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" id="three"/>Three
<span id="increment-me">10</span>
```

And I need to figure out a way of increasing value in real time by X amount based on checkboxes clicked. For example by 5 if #one is checked,and by 7 more if #two is checked etc.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I cant really write JS myself so I'm been sticking some scripts I find together.

$("#increment-me").change( function() {
var value = "10";
  if ( $(".one").is(":checked") ) {
     $('#increment-me').text($value + 5);
  } 
});

Comment: have you tried searching on SO?

Comment: Of coure. Maybe I cant formulate what I need properly.

Comment: [something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/27g1febj/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## demo

http://jsfiddle.net/xt1paLva/

## html

```
  <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" id ="one" increment="1"/>+1
    <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" id="two" increment="3"/>+2
    <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" id="three" increment="3"/>+3
<br>
<span id="increment-me">0</span>
```

## jquery

```
$('input').change(function(e){
    var c = $(this).is(":checked");
    var i = parseInt($(this).attr('increment'));
    var current_value = parseInt($('span#increment-me').text());
    if (c){
        $('span#increment-me').text(current_value+i);
    }else{
        $('span#increment-me').text(current_value-i);
    }
})
```